# Name of the thread not being shown properly in transaction system

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have created a transaction system which seem to work perfectly with synchronized threading.
However, I want the name on the person doing the transaction, in the following case (`Emily` and `John`) to be displayed instead of thread number.

Following is the code:

```
public class SharedAccountDriver {

  static int balance = 400;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SharedAccount sa = new SharedAccount(balance);
    SharedAccountClient c1 = new SharedAccountClient(sa, "JOHN");
    SharedAccountClient c2 = new SharedAccountClient(sa, "EMILY");
    double x1 = 1000.00;
    double x2 = -400;

    c1.setTransaction(x1);
    c2.setTransaction(x2);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(c1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(c2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}

public class SharedAccountClient implements Runnable {
  double transaction;
  SharedAccount sa;
  static String name;

  public SharedAccountClient(SharedAccount sa, String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.sa = sa;
    name = string;
  }

  public void setTransaction(double transaction) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
  }

  public void run() {
    sa.completeTransaction(transaction, name);

  }
}

public class SharedAccount {
  private double balance;

  public SharedAccount(double initialAmount) {
    balance = initialAmount;
  }

  public synchronized void completeTransaction(double amount, String name) {
    double temp = this.balance + amount;

    if (amount < 0)
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Withdrawing: "
          + Math.abs(amount));
    else
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Depositing: "
          + amount);

    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Transaction interrupted.");
    }

    balance = temp;
    System.out.println("Current Balance: " + balance);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
 Thread-0Depositing: 1000.0
 Current Balance: 1400.0
 Thread-1Withdrawing: 400.0
 Current Balance: 1000.0
```

Instead of `Thread-0` and `Thread-1`, I want the names, `Emily` & `John`

Comment: Why would the name of a client be static? Each client has his/her own name, right? And if you want the client name to be printed, why don't you print it, instead of printing `Thread.currentThread().getName()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `Thread.currentThread().getName()`? You haven't changed that value (by using `Thread.setName()` or by using the constructor `new Thread(runnable, name)`).

Just use the method argument `name` that you're passing in, e.g.

```
System.out.println(name + "Withdrawing: " + Math.abs(amount));
```

---

As an aside, why is the field `String name` declared `static`ally? That means it will change each time you call the constructor, so both objects will have the same `name`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Thread.currentThread().getName() return the name of the thread, not the object in the thread, you can use instead the constructor `Thread(Runnable target, String name)`

In your case, use something like:

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(c1, c1.getName());
 Thread t2 = new Thread(c2, c2.getName());
```